# Invalid graphics state model4you

Tags: r, graphics, decision-tree, palette, party

Following the model-based recursive partitioning in https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6015941/ I want to replicate the following code:

```
sim_data <- function(n=2000){
  x1 <- rnorm(n)
x2 <- rbinom(n,1,0.3)
x3 <- runif(n)
x4 <- rnorm(n)
t <- rbinom(n,1,0.5)
z <- 1-x2+x1+2*(x1>=0)*x2*t-2*(x1<0)*x2*t
pr <- 1/(1+exp(-z))
y <- as.factor(rbinom(n,1,pr))
data.frame(x1,x3,x2=as.factor(x2),x4, t=factor(t,labels=c("C","A")),y,z)
}
dt <- sim_data()

dt.num = as.data.frame(sapply(dt, as.numeric))
dt.num$y <- dt.num$y-1    #only to convert outcome 1,2 into 0,1
mbase <- glm(y~t, data=dt.num,
             family = binomial())
round(summary(mbase)$coefficients,3)
library("model4you")
pmtr <- pmtree(mbase, zformula = ~. ,
               data = dt.num,
               control = ctree_control(minbucket = 250))

plot(pmtr, terminal_panel = node_pmterminal(pmtr,
                                            plotfun = binomial_glm_plot,
                                            confint = TRUE))
```

However, the following inexplicable error occurs:

```
Error in .Call.graphics(C_palette2, .Call(C_palette2, NULL)) : 
  invalid graphics state
```

I was looking for a solution to this problem in the post [Persistent invalid graphics state error when using ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20155581/persistent-invalid-graphics-state-error-when-using-ggplot2/56289002). But the problem persists.

Any clue?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

When I tried to replicate this, I got a different error:

```
plot(pmtr, terminal_panel = node_pmterminal(pmtr, plotfun = binomial_glm_plot, confint = TRUE))
## Waiting for profiling to be done...
## Error in plotfun(mod = list(coefficients = c(`(Intercept)` = -0.16839363929017,  : 
##   Plotting currently only works for models with a single factor covariate. 
##         We recommend using partykit or ggparty plotting functionalities!
```

The reason for this is that the panel function expects both the response and the treatment to be binary factors (as in `dt`). When you use binary numeric variables instead (as in `dt.num`) the model estimation in `glm()` leads to equivalent output but the `plot()` functionality is confused.

When I refit both the `glm()` and the `pmtree()` with `dt` rather than `dt.num` everything works as intended for me, yielding the following graphic:

[image: pmtree plot]